# Highcharter plot fails in shiny after loading ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-highcharter

In my shiny app, I want to create a line plot where the `group` value is based on selected user input: `input$tt_groupvar`. Highcharter can do this using `hcaes_string`, but my app in real life loads ggplot2, and the `hchart` fails.

In app1 below, ggplot2 is NOT explicitly loaded, and the plot correctly groups the data based on `input$tt_groupvar`. But in app2 below, *where the only difference is that ggplot2 is loaded*, the app fails. After ggplot2 is loaded thru app2, app1 no longer works correctly.

I know that I can make this work properly using ggplot2 or plotly, but I REALLY want to use highcharter. Is there any way to get around this?

Any insight at all is much appreciated!

app1

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)

df <- data.frame(floorDate = as.Date(c("01/01/2017", "01/01/2017", "01/01/2017", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2019", "01/01/2019", "01/01/2019", "06/01/2017", "11/01/2018", "12/01/2019"), format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
                   location = c("MWH", "MWH", "MWH", "MWH", "SH", "MWH","MWH","MWH", "SH", "SH", "MIF", "MIF"),
                   ethnicity = c("W", "W", "B", "B", "MULT", "MULT","MULT","W","W","B","MULT","B"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("my title"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Select a grouping variable to plot the number of ROCs 
               by the values in that group across January 2017 to January 2020."),

      selectizeInput("tt_groupvar",
                     label = "Choose a grouping variable:",
                     choices = c("Location"="location", "Ethnicity"="ethnicity"),
                     multiple = FALSE,
                     selected = c("location"))
      ),

    mainPanel(
      highchartOutput("timeTrend_1")
      )
  )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$timeTrend_1 <- renderHighchart({
    hchart(df %>% 
             group_by_at(c("floorDate", input$tt_groupvar)) %>%
             count(),
           type = "line",
           hcaes_string(x = "floorDate", y = "n", group = input$tt_groupvar)) %>% #THE ISSUE IS HERE!!!!
      hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "")) %>%
      hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "# of ROCs")) %>%
      hc_title(text = "Number of ROCs per Month by Group from 2017 to January 2019")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

app2

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)
library(ggplot2)


df <- data.frame(floorDate = as.Date(c("01/01/2017", "01/01/2017", "01/01/2017", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2019", "01/01/2019", "01/01/2019", "06/01/2017", "11/01/2018", "12/01/2019"), format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
                   location = c("MWH", "MWH", "MWH", "MWH", "SH", "MWH","MWH","MWH", "SH", "SH", "MIF", "MIF"),
                   ethnicity = c("W", "W", "B", "B", "MULT", "MULT","MULT","W","W","B","MULT","B"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("my title"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Select a grouping variable to plot the number of ROCs 
               by the values in that group across January 2017 to January 2020."),

      selectizeInput("tt_groupvar",
                     label = "Choose a grouping variable:",
                     choices = c("Location"="location", "Ethnicity"="ethnicity"),
                     multiple = FALSE,
                     selected = c("location"))
      ),

    mainPanel(
      highchartOutput("timeTrend_1")
      )
  )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$timeTrend_1 <- renderHighchart({
    hchart(df %>% 
             group_by_at(c("floorDate", input$tt_groupvar)) %>%
             count(),
           type = "line",
           hcaes_string(x = "floorDate", y = "n", group = input$tt_groupvar)) %>% # THE ISSUE IS HERE!
      hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "")) %>%
      hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "# of ROCs")) %>%
      hc_title(text = "Number of ROCs per Month by Group from 2017 to January 2019")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Why do you load `ggplot` if you don't want to use it and you have a working version without it?

Comment: I found an issue on github about [this](https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/476). I understood the issue has to do with certain versions of `rlang` and `ggplot2`. Is it possible to upgrade these packages?

Comment: @andrew_reece, Sorry for the lack of clarity. My actual app in real life has other tabs and loads ggplot2 for other parts of the app, so I can't seem to avoid the issue its causing ```highcharter```. I'm just really hoping to use ```highcharter``` in my app in this way, and loading ```ggplot2``` is making it unusable. I wrote out the post like this to demonstrate that I thought ```ggplot2``` was the culprit. Hope this helps clear that up.

Comment: @ricoderks, thanks for the suggestion, but I reinstalled ggplot2 (3.2.1), rlang (0.4.4), and highcharter (0.7.0) to get the most up-to-date versions, and the issue persists. Could it be that I don't have the most recent version of R? I'm using R version 3.6.0.

Comment: Aaah crap, sorry @jpopel!! Just noticed that I didn't load `ggplot2`. Was trying so many things that I didn't notice it!! I'll delete my answer!!